# Any bugs on FastText.build_vocab?

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext, incremental-build

I cannot update the training of my gensim fasttext model with the command : model.build_vocab

I think the key is "AttributeError: 'FastText' object has no attribute 'syn1neg'"

Please give me some suggestion. Thanks a lot

#### Load the pre-trained model, not pretrained vector to make sure that i can train the model

print('load fasttext pretrain model ')
pretrained_model=FastText_gensim.load(pretrained_model_file)

#### Load the tokens of articles i wanna update and convert the tokens into list of list

sent=token_df['token'].values.tolist()

use the ".build_vocab" of  pretrain model and state "update = True"

pretrained_model.build_vocab(sent,update=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/marcus/PycharmProjects/DIVA_CWS/FastText_pretrain.py", line 313, in 
pretrained_model.build_vocab(sent,update=True)
File "C:\Users\marcus\Desktop\DIVA_CWS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 712, in build_vocab
self.finalize_vocab(update=update)  # build tables & arrays
File "C:\Users\marcus\Desktop\DIVA_CWS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 953, in finalize_vocab
self.update_weights()
File "C:\Users\marcus\Desktop\DIVA_CWS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 1373, in update_weights
self.syn1neg = vstack([self.syn1neg, zeros((gained_vocab, self.layer1_size), dtype=REAL)])
AttributeError: 'FastText' object has no attribute 'syn1neg'

Comment: You're not showing where the `FastText_gensim` variable has been imported/created. But also, I'm not sure any of the `gensim` `FastText` support has ever supported the `.build_vocab(..., update=True)` option for expanding the vocabulary of an existing model. Are you basing your work on any documentation or examples which indicate this should work?

Answer (score 3):

Change the import statement from

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText
```

to

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText
```

this should solve the problem.